# Casting a flat pointer to a multidimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to get the compiler to do the same pointer arithmetic on flat pointers as it does on multidimensional arrays?

With multidimensional arrays, the pointer arithmetic appears to work as follows:

```
int main(void)
{
    char ar[2][3][4];
#define At(a,x,y,z) printf("["#x"]["#y"]["#z"]=%ld\n", &(a)[x][y][z] - &(a)[0][0][0]);
    At(ar,0,0,0);
    At(ar,0,0,1);
    At(ar,0,0,2);
    At(ar,0,0,3);
puts("");
    At(ar,0,1,0);
    At(ar,0,2,0);
    At(ar,0,3,0);
puts("");
    At(ar,1,0,0);
    At(ar,2,0,0);
    At(ar,3,0,0);
/*
    [0][0][0]=0
    [0][0][1]=1
    [0][0][2]=2
    [0][0][3]=3

    [0][1][0]=4  // 1 * 4
    [0][2][0]=8  // 2 * 4
    [0][3][0]=12 // 3 * 4

    [1][0][0]=12 // 1 * 3 * 4
    [2][0][0]=24 // 2 * 3 * 4
    [3][0][0]=36 // 3 * 3 * 4 
*/
}
```

So I tried:

```
    char *blk;
    if(!(blk=malloc(1000))) return -1;
    char (*p)[2][3][4] = (char(*)[2][3][4])blk;

    At(p,0,0,0);
    At(p,0,0,1);
    At(p,0,0,2);
    At(p,0,0,3);
puts("");
    At(p,0,1,0);
    At(p,0,2,0);
    At(p,0,3,0);
puts("");
    At(p,1,0,0);
    At(p,2,0,0);
    At(p,3,0,0);

/*
    [0][0][0]=0
    [0][0][1]=1
    [0][0][2]=2
    [0][0][3]=3

    [0][1][0]=3
    [0][2][0]=6
    [0][3][0]=9

    [1][0][0]=6
    [2][0][0]=12
    [3][0][0]=18
*/
}
```

But as you can see, this doesn't give corresponding results. 
What exactly is going on here? Can the results be made to match?

Comment: `char (*p)[2][3][4] = (char(*)[2][3][4])&blk;` Using p from this point on is undefined behavior.

Comment: @2501 `char *blk = malloc(1000); if(!blk) return -1; char (*p)[2][3][4] = (char(*)[2][3][4])blk` better?

Comment: One is defined, the other isn't. And you're allocating too much memory since 1000 isn't divisible by 24.

Comment: OT: Doing `void * blk;` would drop the need for this ugly cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a dereference. You now have a pointer to a 3 dimensional array.

You need to do this:

```
At(*p, 0, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You added an extra dimension, try this instead:

```
char (*p)[3][4] = (char(*)[3][4])blk;
```

Also note that your `printf` format is incorrect: the difference of 2 pointers has type `ptrdiff_t`, the corresponding format length modifier is `t`:

```
#define At(a,x,y,z) printf("["#x"]["#y"]["#z"]=%td\n", &(a)[x][y][z] - &(a)[0][0][0]);
```

If your C library is not fully C99 compliant, you should use a cast:

```
#define At(a,x,y,z) printf("["#x"]["#y"]["#z"]=%ld\n", (long)(&(a)[x][y][z] - &(a)[0][0][0]));
```